# How to generate success alerts in jsp after successful execution of a servlet?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page which contains a form which calls a servlet, after inserting data into the database by a servlet hot to display successs alert to the user on the page?

Thanks in advance for answering.

Comment: You can set message in request object.

Comment: see this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/10137269/985143.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you call the servlet asynchronously with AJAX and have a success callback function (see jQuery example: http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/ )

Or you do it the old fashioned way with a synchronous Post which loads a success page, or the same page with for example a query parameter that states that you have succeed. This could then be used to activate a script block in your JSP (or whatever template language is your flavour).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a javascript alert box. See http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp